# Opening html page in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC project. For each request it returns jsp page. But for specific URL's it should return html page? What should I do for that?? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by HTML page ? You always send HTML to client ! Did you mean that you want to return some static HTML pages for certain URLs ?

Answer (score 1):

`<mvc:resources>` may be what you are looking for.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I always use mvc:resources tag for static resources which do need processing or security.